# TCP/IP: message got by recv() in order without keep buffer

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a client-server programm. They communicate with some characters.

```
ex:
client --send A-> server
then
client <-recv A'-- server
```

**But I let server send message back not in order.**

```
ex:
client --A--> --B--> --C--> server
then
client <--A'-- <--C'-- <--B'-- server
what I want:
client <--A'-- <--B'-- <--C'-- server
```

so I want to handle the situation **in client programm**.

I only figure out one way is to **keep a buffer** to record data from server, and client will check the B' received and then check the C' received in order.

Is there anyway to do that in client and avoid using buffer?

Comment: This is only possible if you have a bug in your code. TCP preserves the order of bytes sent.

Comment: @EJP not bug, I design the server to send characters back not in order

Comment: Really. One question. Why? Why build in a deliberate bug at one end that you don't know how to solve at the other end?

Comment: @EJP It depends on my system. Client tell server to download "mission A", and then server tell client " A' " if mission A complete. Now client tell server to download "mission A" and "mission B", but mission A took lots of time to download more than B. So server tell client " B' " first than "A' ". That's why I have the problem LOL.

Comment: So have the client issue each request on a new connection. Then you don't have a self-created problem.

Comment: @EJP It's wasty on fd for me. Maybe keep the received message in buffer still is the better choice. thx

Comment: Not if you don't know how to program it, and when you have programmed it it is still extra code to be maintained. Keep It Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should send and then wait for reply, send next request when you received earlier reply.
But apparently your client seems to send without waiting for reply and server replies whichever request its done processing.

In such case you need to device a mechanism in your client and server program based on the data being sent and received.

You can decide your client and server will work on data having(Header+data) format something like:

```
length(2 bytes) - length of actual data
sequence numner(2 bytes) - to be incremented for each request
Actual data(length number of bytes)
```

When you send the data keep the request data, after sending over socket, in a pending list of requests waiting for reply from server.
The server on receiving request in above format, will update its reply data in the 'Actual data' section , update the length in header, keeping sequence as it is, server will send reply to client.
Client will match the sequence number from reply with the items in its pending list to get the request whose reply it received from server

Comment: Why? How can the data ever get out of sequence?

Comment: I am not saying data is getting out of sequence, it is for the situation when server receives request data A and then B, it decides to reply B and then A, I know TCP has mechanism in place to send data in sequence, ie if request data A has multiple bytes, then will reach in same sequence as they were sent

Comment: @Pras TCP will keep the order. But I let server send characters back to client not in order. Maybe I need to check the content validity in client. I just want to know any function or api can handle this. thx

Comment: Yes - a protocol with sequence numbers, as described, or some other protocol that can match up requests with responses.  You have to do this.